# Plese write a solution for a prolog task

Tags: arrays, list, prolog

I have a matrix `M x N`, I need to switch places of the elements with indexed `[1,N]` and `[M,N]`.

**Update**

I am really new to Prolog, here is my solution that returns false :(

```
main([FirstRow|Tail],X):-
    last(FirstRow, A),
    last(Tail, LastRow),
    last(LastRow, B),
    skipLastItem(FirstRow,FirstRowWithoutA),
    skipLastItem(LastRow,LastRowWithoutB),
    append(FirstRowWithoutA,[B],FirstRowNew),
    append(LastRowWithoutB,[A],LastRowNew),
    assign([FirstRowNew],X),
    skipLastItem(Tail,Middle),
    appendAllElements(Middle,X),
    append(X,LastRowNew,X).

appendAllElements([X|Tail],List):-
    append(List,X,NewList),
    appendAllElements(Tail,NewList).

appendAllElements([],_).

assign(Item,Item).

skipLastItem([_],[ ]) :- !.
skipLastItem([H|T],[H|S]) :-
skipLastItem(T,S).
```

Comment: How about you write a solution first, and let us know where you run into trouble?

Comment: I predict that, yes, somebody can write a solution to your problem in prolog.

Comment: So, I provided you with solution, can you help me?

Comment: @Eugene add your code to your question not as a reply

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like homework, so I'm going to be a bit vague here...

Start with the simpler problem of replacing one value in a list. Write a recursive predicate

```
swap_list(X,N,A,B,Y)
```

which should be read as "for a list X, at position N, removing the value A and replacing it with B gives the list Y".

Now we can extend this to the case of matrices. Write a second recursive predicate

```
swap_matrix(X,M,N,A,B,Y)
```

which should be read as "for a matrix X, at position (M,N), removing element A and replacing it with B gives the matrix Y". The base case of this recursion, where `M=0`, will contain a call to `swap_list`.

Now, you can swap two positions (M1,N1) and (M2,N2) with the following:

```
swap(X,M1,N1,M2,N2,Y) :-
    swap_matrix(X,M1,N1,A,B,Z),
    swap_matrix(Z,M2,N2,B,A,Y).
```

Note that we insert `B` into the matrix `Z` before we even know what it is - B isn't assigned a value until the second `swap_matrix` call.